# Transitivity of Divisibility problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Prove or disprove: for all integers a,b and c, if a|b and a|c, then a|(4b-6c)?

By definition:

b = ar
c = as

$ r,s \in \mathbb{Z}$

then substitute values :

4b - 4c = (4ar - 6as)

you can factor out the a:

a(4r - 6s)

t = 4r-6s, $ t\in \mathbb{Z} $

so :

at = (4b -6c)

Comment: So where are your doubts ?

Comment: @DietrichBurde t = 4r-6s didn't know if that was correct

Comment: The argument is fine. The title is not, since what you have proved is not transitivity. Transitivity is the fact that if $a\mid b$ and $b\mid c$ then $a\mid c$.  (Transitivity does hold.)